# How can I create a mold for an atypical shape for 3D printing using Fusion 360?

Tags: 3d-models, fusion360, medical

I have an STL file of a bone, and I want to create a mold to fill in with bone cement for a drilling exercise.

However, a midline cut through the mold doesn't work as the bone is atypically shaped. I would like to create a plane that follows either one of the bone's surfaces to create a mold that separates well.

Shape of the bone

[image: Shape of the bone]

This doesn't work, as you might expect:

[image: This doesn't work, as you might expect]

It should look like this:

[image: It should look like this]

<sup>Image source: The third photo from [Cranioplasty Welcomes 3D Printed Molds for Reconstructive Surgery in Russia](https://3dprint.com/61320/cranioplasty-3d-printed-molds)</sup>